# Type II ANOVA, post hoc test needed

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

i`ve been struggling a while now with my R problem.
I have a data set, were independent variable A and B are applied in the same three different concentrations to my study animals. Because there is no interaction between the independent variables, i choose an ANOVA Type II (right?).
Now i get a significant p-value for the concentration and want to perform an post hoc test to see were exactly it is significant, but i cant make it work.
i tried glht, Tukey, TukeyHSD and am at a dead end.

```
summary(glht(aovA, linfct=mcp(Material = "Tukey")), 
        test = adjusted(type = "bonferroni"))
TukeyHSD(aovA)
```

Is there any other way to perform a post hoc here?
Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: So its about a mussel data set, which were fed pvc and red clay at 1.5, 15 150 mg/l
did an anova:

```
ModelA<-aov(Number_of_threads~Particle_concentration*Particle_type,data = data)
```

then decided to do the type `II` anova for the reason above
`aovA<-Anova(ModelA, type="II")`

and am now struggeling with the post hoc

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Closevote. Need debugging details. Need [MCVE]. No response to reasonalbe request to edit question for clarification.